# Unity blank compiler errors with no details

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

On a new, very basic project I was working on, I suddenly started getting blank compiler errors with no details about what *actually* has gone wrong. If I start a new project, that project will also have these errors. I figured out that the only difference between these new projects and my old ones (which still work, load, and compile without any errors) was that the %project%/Library/ScriptAssemblies/ directory is empty.

Copying the contents of that directory from an older project into the newer one will make the errors go away temporarily on a project that has NO scripts in it - The moment I include a script the project becomes unusable again. I have spent all day googling this every way conceivable and yet I cannot find any information that actually helps me solve this problem. Most links are unrelated or don't contain useful info.

The error is as follows:

```
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.1.65535 (9d34608e)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

There is NO additional detail to help me figure out what went wrong. That is the entire error. Appears 4x in console prior to copying that directories contents, afterwards it only appears once. This is what appears in Editor.log;

```
 -----CompilerOutput:-stdout--exitcode: 1--compilationhadfailure: True--outfile: Temp/Assembly-CSharp.dll
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.1.65535 (9d34608e)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------
The system cannot find the path specified.
-----EndCompilerOutput---------------
- Finished compile Library/ScriptAssemblies/Assembly-CSharp.dll
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.1.65535 (9d34608e)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

I have (unsuccessfully) tried;
  - Changing scripting runtime version
  - Changing scripting backend
  - Changing API compatibility level
  - Deleting all META files from assets and reloading project
  - Reimporting all assets
  - Restarting Unity after forcibly closing ALL related tasks
  - Installing a new version of Unity (2019.3) and starting a NEW project.

Unity Version is 2019.1, I have both VS2015 and VS community 2017 installed.

Comment: do you have any errors in event manager?

Comment: What event manager are you referring to? Other than the error I listed I have no other errors anywhere else.

Comment: It might also be worth a quick try to install a secondary Unity version via Hub and make that the latest (2019.3.0f6), then copy the project and see if when opened via that it works. If so, you could decide upgrading. If not, at least you ruled it out.

Comment: event manager, the one that comes with windows...

Comment: I'm not sure what I would look for as far as errors go in Event Viewer but I don't see anything within the last 24 hours that seems to be related to my problem, Unity, or anything MSVC*** etc

Comment: Verified that a new install of an up-to-date Unity still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

yeah many people including myself have been having this problem since 2019 first came out, i've been stuck using unity 2018 which actually works without any problems.

I've tried talking to unity support and given them logs but nothing has come from it. I also have tried every "solution" that I have found online. The best bet would be to just stick with unity 2018.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to see if I can download an earlier version and have any better luck.